# Return to while loop condition if error occurs inside methods contained within the statements

Tags: java

In the below lines of code ,I am calling validatePersonDTO method inside a while loop.I need to return back to while loop to process next record if any error occurs within validatePersonDTO's methods for the current record.

> Note:

ValidatepersonDTo method is in another class from where the while loop exists.

This is a very basic question , i have tried out some options , but neither continue or return wouldn't work.

So kindly let me know of your suggestions.

```
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
hrUploadValidator.validatePersonDTO(personDTO);
}

public void validatePersonDTO(PersonDTO personDTO) {
    try {           
        validateCdsId(personDTO, logDTO,regionIdList);          
        validateEmpFirstName(personDTO, logDTO);            
        validateEmpLastName(personDTO, logDTO);         
        validateEffectiveIn(personDTO, logDTO);
}
```

Comment: Please post compilable code. What do you mean exactly by "if any error occurs within validatePersonDTO"?

Comment: Hi Nizet,if inside validateCdsId() method i am facing an error like,the current record's cdsid is invalid according to project specs,it is an error.So i need to skip the record and exit from  validateCdsId() method and also skip the remaining 3 methods and return to while condition to process the next record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `validatePersonDTO` throws an exception when validation fails (it's the only option, since the method is `void`), you are missing a try/catch block inside your `while` loop:

```
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    try {
        hrUploadValidator.validatePersonDTO(personDTO);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Log / otherwise process your exception here
    }
}
```

Once the exception is logged or otherwise processed in the `catch` block, your loop will continue its iterations from where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `try`/`catch` to your loop code, like this:

```
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
{
    try
    {
        hrUploadValidator.validatePersonDTO(personDTO);
    }
    catch (Throwable x)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the method `validatePersonDTO` throws an `Exception`, then you can surround its call with a `try-catch` and in the catch statement do the `continue` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react to the exceptions, don't catch them in `validatePersonDTO` but instead in the while loop:

```
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
  try {           
    hrUploadValidator.validatePersonDTO(personDTO);
  } catch (ErrorThrownByValidationMethods e) {
    continue;
  } 
  // Processing
}

public void validatePersonDTO(PersonDTO personDTO) throw ErrorThrownByValidationMethods {

    validateCdsId(personDTO, logDTO,regionIdList);          
    validateEmpFirstName(personDTO, logDTO);            
    validateEmpLastName(personDTO, logDTO);         
    validateEffectiveIn(personDTO, logDTO);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a flag of boolean identifier which returns a true value from the method where the while is executed (if it executes successfully) then move forward or if false is returned then go again in the method and update the values.

you can do like this

```
 boolean x=false;
   while(<your condition>&&x==false)
  {
     try
       {
          <your code>
          x=true; //last statement of try block
       }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        x=false;
     }
  }
```